# Swift: Why localization sometime need to add observer to get it work but sometime don't

Tags: ios, swift3, swift4

I have been developed an app that needs to use localization so I've chosen [this nice library](https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift) for my application. but I just confuse that in their document mention that they need to use observer notification to listen to when language has changed. but in my main controller, I just do what they said and it's working like a charm but when I add localization to my sidebar text. I got this error:

**reason: '-[NSConcreteNotification length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x107cbb9f0'**

but if I remove the observer inside the sidebar controller. it'll be working fine. **So My Question is why do some controller need to add an observer to work but some doesn't need to add it to work**

This is MySidebar Controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
         NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(setText), name: NSNotification.Name(LCLLanguageChangeNotification), object: nil)     
    }
deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
@objc func setText(status: String) {
   item = "item".localized(using: "NavigationDrawerViewController")
}
```

This is ChooseLanguageController:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        Localize.setCurrentLanguage(availableLanguages[indexPath.row])
        mytable.reloadData()
    }
```

*sorry in advance if my English seems confuse*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signature of selector must have `Notification` as an argument not `String`. Like this

```
@objc func setText(notification: Notification) {

}
```

From Documentation

> Selector that specifies the message the receiver sends
>   observer to notify it of the notification posting. The method
>   specified by aSelector must have one and only one argument (an
>   instance of NSNotification).

For more details see [addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1415360-addobserver)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. the thing is this is my mainview controller code for set text `@objc func setText()  {
        templeTxt.text = "temple".localized(using: "MainViewController")
    }` and it's working fine that's why i don't put it in my sidebar controller either.

Comment: diff is the `status` argument.  `setText(status: String)` vs `func setText()`.  `func setText()` or `func setText(notification: Notification)` both will work but `func setText(status:String)` will crash.

Comment: ahhh! i see. i got what you point out about my problem and i think that is it. but just another point in my question is  that **Why In my main controller need observer to work but if i remove it, the localize won't work. and it's different from the sidebar controller that if i put the wrong argument it'll crush but if i remove the whole observer notification it'll work even i don't know how is it listen to** i don't understand this logic

Comment: It’s hard to comment without seeing the code. But you can easily do debugging, just add breakpoints where you are setting localised text in your viewcontroller. Now run the app and change language, when breakpoint hits you can see stacktrace and findout.

Comment: thank you for the advice. it's helping me a lot. I'll try.